# Can't get prices of a product by web scraping in Python

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I have been leaning to web scrape, so I decided to practice a bit.
Using this website (https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/razer?matt_tool=6263806&matt_word=RAZER_MERCADO_LIVRE&gclid=CjwKCAiAs8XiBRAGEiwAFyQ-ejETB12X8G75icDJLMkW4ChSyBsJLrL3wZv_o3oZb8zvtUsc5D1tZBoCsNEQAvD_BwE), I thought I'd try to collect the description and price of each product in the first page. I was able to get descriptions just fine, but I've had an issue with prices.

For instance, given the first product, the price is the number 559. However, when I use `produto1.div.span.text`, Python only gives me the "R$", which I do not want. 
What can I do to get just the actual price?

My code:

```
url = 'https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/razer?matt_tool=6263806&matt_word=RAZER_MERCADO_LIVRE&gclid=CjwKCAiAs8XiBRAGEiwAFyQ-ejETB12X8G75icDJLMkW4ChSyBsJLrL3wZv_o3oZb8zvtUsc5D1tZBoCsNEQAvD_BwE'
response = get(url)
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
produtos = html_soup.find_all('div', class_ = "item__info item__info--with-reviews")

produto1 = produtos[0]
produto1.div.span.text
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
You code does not run as posted: BS isn't imported, and `get` is unresolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have many options

a) If you need just the prices then you can just target the prices.

```
produtos = html_soup.find_all('span', class_ = "price__fraction")
print([item.text for item in produtos])
```

Outputs:

```
['559', '395', '378', '66', '349', '148', '39', '422', '39', '195', '314', '63', '844', '147', '399', '899', '239', '739', '469', '564', '28', '487', '1.189', '169', '324', '32', '899', '399', '168', '234', '274', '168', '624', '854', '29', '156', '189', '209', '267', '595', '273', '189', '299', '289', '249', '686', '1.489', '449']
```

b) If you want to get only the price but want to select the `div` to get more items later that is fine too.

```
produtos = html_soup.find_all('div', class_ = "item__info item__info--with-reviews")
produto1 = produtos[0]
print(produto1.find('span',class_='price__fraction').text)
```

Outputs:

```
559
```

Once you have selected the product div getting data out of it is just a matter of proper selection using BeautifulSoup. You can read more in [Searching the tree](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-the-tree) section in the documentation. I will demonstrate how to filter some items using the class and tag name.

[image]

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/razer?matt_tool=6263806&matt_word=RAZER_MERCADO_LIVRE&gclid=CjwKCAiAs8XiBRAGEiwAFyQ-ejETB12X8G75icDJLMkW4ChSyBsJLrL3wZv_o3oZb8zvtUsc5D1tZBoCsNEQAvD_BwE'
response = get(url)
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
produtos = html_soup.find_all('div', class_ = "item__info item__info--with-reviews")
produto1 = produtos[0]
#price symbol
print(produto1.find('span',class_='price__symbol').text)
#price fraction / price
print(produto1.find('span',class_='price__fraction').text)
#main title
print(produto1.find('span','main-title').text.strip())
```

Outputs:

```
R$
559
Razer Combo Holiday - Cynosa+goliathus+deathadder+kraken
```

Comment: This was really helpful! Think you so much! I'll take a better look at my options, try to learn a bit more and see what works better. Have a wonderful day!

Answer (score 0):

There are 10 span tags within the `<div>` object. You're just grabbing the first `<span>` tag.

You could get the next tag by doing:

```
produto1.div.span.find_next('span').text
```

You can see it by finding all the `<span>` tags, then loop through it:

```
import requests
import bs4

url = 'https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/razer?matt_tool=6263806&matt_word=RAZER_MERCADO_LIVRE&gclid=CjwKCAiAs8XiBRAGEiwAFyQ-ejETB12X8G75icDJLMkW4ChSyBsJLrL3wZv_o3oZb8zvtUsc5D1tZBoCsNEQAvD_BwE'
response = requests.get(url)
html_soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
produtos = html_soup.find_all('div', class_ = "item__info item__info--with-reviews")

produto1 = produtos[0]

span_tags = produto1.find_all('span')

i = 0
for span in span_tags:
    print ('Element: '+ str(i) +' Text: ' + span.text.strip())
    i += 1
```

**Output:**

```
Element: 0 Text: R$
Element: 1 Text: 559
Element: 2 Text: 12x   R$ 53 43
Element: 3 Text: 12x
Element: 4 Text: R$ 53 43
Element: 5 Text: 
Element: 6 Text: Razer Combo Holiday - Cynosa+goliathus+deathadder+kraken
Element: 7 Text: por Razer
Element: 8 Text: por Razer
Element: 9 Text: por Razer
```

Comment: Great answer! You just gave me new ways to navigate through the code and that's really helpful! Have a wonderful day as well!